# Print method for variadic template pairs in C++

Tags: c++, templates, cout, variadic, parameter-pack

I want to achieve something like:

```cpp
export_vars("path/to/file.dat", {"variable_name", obj}, {"another_variable", 2});
```

where `obj` can be any type as long as it has an `<<` overload - the idea is to write to an `ofstream` later on. I have tried (for an `initializer_list` of pairs):

```cpp
void
export_vars(const std::string& path, std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::string, std::any>> args)
{       
    for (auto& [name, var] : args)
        std::cout << name << ": " << var << std::endl;
}
```

but `std::any` cannot be `<<` without knowing the underlying type. Can it maybe be achieved using variadic templates and parameter pack expansion? I also tried something like:

```cpp
template <class... Args>
void
export_vars(const std::string& path, Args... args)
{   
    (std::cout << ... << args.first << args.second) << std::endl;
}
```

but that's obviously wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your problem is `{stuff, other_stuff}` has no type.  You cant do type deduction on something that has no type.

Comment: Yeah, I got that error at first. Is it not doable at all using pairs?

Comment: It would be: `((std::cout <<args.first << ": " << args.second << std::endl), ...);` [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59ef9489579ec005)

Comment: Oh damn! Unfortunately I still get the `Candidate template ignored: substitution failure: deduced incomplete pack <(no value)> for template parameter 'Args'` as @NathanOliver mentioned.

Comment: However, this works: `export_vars("path", std::pair{ "hello", 1 }, std::pair{ "hello", "world" });` .. is there anyway to help the compiler deduce that's its a pair with variadic templates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{..}` has no type, and so disallows most deduction.

Several work arounds:

- Change call to use `std::pair` explicitly:

  ```
  template <typename ... Pairs>
  void export_vars(const std::string&, const Pairs&... args)
  {       
      ((std::cout << args.first << ": " << args.second << std::endl), ...);
  }

  int main()
  {
      export_vars("unused", std::pair{"int", 42}, std::pair{"cstring", "toto"});
  }
  ```

  [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59ef9489579ec005)
- Don't use template:

  ```
  void export_vars(const std::string&,
                   const std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::string, Streamable>>& args)
  {
      for (const auto& [name, value] : args) {
          std::cout << name << ": " << value << std::endl;
      }
  }
  int main()
  {
      export_vars("unused", {{"int", 42}, {"cstring", "toto"}});
  }
  ```

  with `Streamable` using type-erasure, possibly something like:

  ```
  class Streamable
  {
      struct IStreamable
      {
          virtual ~IStreamable() = default;
          virtual void print(std::ostream&) = 0;
      };

      template <typename T>
      struct StreamableT : IStreamable
      {
          StreamableT(T t) : data(std::forward<T>(t)) {}
          virtual void print(std::ostream& os) { os << data; }

          T data;
      };

      std::unique_ptr<IStreamable> ptr;
  public:
      template <typename T>
      // Possibly some concepts/SFINAE as requires(is_streamable<T>)
      Streamable(T&& t) : ptr{std::make_unique<StreamableT<std::decay_t<T>>>(t)} {}

      friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Streamable& streamable)
      {
          streamable.ptr->print(os);
          return os;
      } 
  };
  ```

  [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca732ecb6a9009b7)

Comment: I think this might be the best solution; otherwise `export_vars("path", "name1", var1, "name2", var2, ...)` with fold expressions might also be a decent way to go.

Comment: Hi Jarod42.    Your answer is great. just convert any type to some type that can be streamed. I am quite new in c++. But I  think your code can de done with concept. since the value is any type that can be streamed..I am afraid that if my question too stupid, I will got banned again. So my question is how to rewrite your code using concepts.

Comment: @Mark: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3rfGh45Mj) with concept.

Answer (score 2):

A templated recursive function can solve this problem.

The recursive function takes as parameters:

- the objects that need to pass through all layers, in this case an output stream reference
- followed by objects you want to process one at a time, in this case a string together with a templated object
- lastly followed by variadic parameter pack that captures all remaining arguments.

The recursive function process just the single given pair and then calls itself recursively on the variadic argument.
At the end a trivial function is needed to end the recursion.

In this case, it's easier to use an output stream reference as that can be passed on recursively. You'll need to handle opening the file etc. in another function.

An example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

void export_vars(std::ostream& o)
{
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void export_vars(std::ostream& o, const std::string& name, const T& var, Args&&... args)
{       
    o << name << ": " << var << std::endl;
    export_vars(o, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main()
{
    export_vars(std::cout, "test", int(0), "test2", unsigned(1));
}
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/v9Gv9MG5d

In this case I chose to simply put the name and variable as separate objects as this actually requires the least syntax in use.

Pairs can of course also be used:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void export_vars(std::ostream& o, const std::pair<std::string,T>& var, Args&&... args)
{       
    o << var.first << ": " << var.second << std::endl;
    export_vars(o, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

However, you cannot use the desired `{"str",var}` syntax with it as the compiler won't know to which type it should convert to. But `std::make_pair("str",var)` or `std::pair{"str",var}` should work.

Comment: Prefer fold expression over recursive template functions. Faster to compile, with less instantiation

Comment: You certainly gave interesting solutions without recursion that I didn't think of! But I guess it does boil down to preference. Since the `std::pair` solution require more syntax in use. And doesn't the type-erasure solution also suffer from more instantiation (besides quite more code)?

Comment: You can enforce `std::pair` without recursion with `template<typename ...Ts> void export_vars(std::ostream& o, const std::pair<std::string,Ts>&... pairs)`. and folding versus recursion is not just a style issue as it has compile time impact.

Comment: Type-erasure solution is not behavior equivalent, so doing comparison against it is not really relevant; but it has one instantiation by type (and doesn't depend of number of arguments contrary to variadic template solution) but has its runtime cost with virtual call.

Comment: @Jardo42 Defining `template<typename... Ts> void export_vars(const std::string& path, const std::pair<std::string,Ts>&... pairs)` unfortunately still doesn't allow for automatic type deduction. Is it safe to assume this not possible, at least not with C++17.

Comment: As already stated `{..}` has no type and limit deduction to only `std::initializer_list<T>`, `T (&)[N]`. So cannot be deduced as `std::pair<T1, T2>`. but when providing types, it would have stronger types (not necessary wanted, `T` cannot be deduced for `std::pair<std::string, T>` from `std::pair<const char*, int>` (as for `std::pair{"", 42}`).

Answer (score 1):

With a little bit of help from [std::any docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/type) I came up with this solution. It is not perfect, because you need to register printing functions (visitors) for each of your type by hand, but then at least you can use your `export_vars` with container of pairs <string, any>, and there are no recursive templates.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Ta3dbWP7h)

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <any>
#include <functional>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeindex>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

template <class T, class F>
inline std::pair<const std::type_index, std::function<void(std::ostream& ostr, std::any const&)>> to_any_visitor(F const& f)
{
    return { std::type_index(typeid(T)), [g = f](std::ostream& ostr, std::any const& a) {
                if constexpr (std::is_void_v<T>)
                    g(ostr);
                else
                    g(ostr, std::any_cast<T const&>(a));
            } };
}

static std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::function<void(std::ostream& ostr, std::any const&)>> any_visitor{
    to_any_visitor<void>([](std::ostream& ostr) { ostr << "{}"; }),
    to_any_visitor<int>([](std::ostream& ostr, int x) { ostr << x; }),
    to_any_visitor<unsigned>([](std::ostream& ostr, unsigned x) { ostr << x; }),
    to_any_visitor<float>([](std::ostream& ostr, float x) { ostr << x; }),
    to_any_visitor<double>([](std::ostream& ostr, double x) { ostr << x; }),
    to_any_visitor<char const*>([](std::ostream& ostr, char const* s) { ostr << std::quoted(s); })
};

void export_vars(std::ostream& ostr, const std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::any>>& args)
{
    for (const auto& [name, var] : args)
    {
        if (const auto it = any_visitor.find(std::type_index(var.type())); it != any_visitor.cend())
        {
            ostr << name << ": ";
            it->second(ostr, var);
            ostr << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Print function not registered");
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::any>> pairs{ { "xxx", 123.456 }, { "yyy", "some text" }, { "zzz", 789 } };
    export_vars(std::cout, pairs);
    export_vars(std::cout, {{"xxx", 123}, {"yyy", 5.6}});  // this will also work
}
```

Comment: With dedicated erasure-type instead of `std::any`, you might avoid registration and have compile time check instead of runtime check.

Comment: @pptaszni I did something alike to begin with, but the manual map makes it non-generic with respect to custom classes etc.